# Combining and ordering dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have multiple dictionaries like so:

```
dict1 = {Jamal: 10, Steve: 20}  
dict2 = {Frank: 200, Steve: 30}  
dict3 = {Carl: 14, Jamal: 26}
```

How would I combine them and order them in descending order of numbers without overwriting any values so that it shows something like:

```
Frank: 200, Steve: 30, Jamal: 26, Steve: 20, Carl: 14, Jamal: 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `Steve` from `dict1`, `dict2`. Mapping types does not allow duplicated keys.

You need to use sequences type (like `list`, `tuple`, ..).

```
>>> dict1 = {'Jamal': 10, 'Steve': 20}
>>> dict2 = {'Frank': 200, 'Steve': 30}
>>> dict3 = {'Carl': 14, 'Jamal': 26}
>>>
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in (dict1, dict2, dict3))
>>> ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(*x) for x in sorted(it, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
'Frank: 200, Steve: 30, Jamal: 26, Steve: 20, Carl: 14, Jamal: 10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a dictionary with duplicate keys, use `OrderedDict` with `dict.setdefault` method to put the relative values in a list :

```
dict1 = {'Jamal': 10, 'Steve': 20}  
dict2 = {'Frank': 200, 'Steve': 30}  
dict3 = {'Carl': 14, 'Jamal': 26}

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter
d = OrderedDict()
for key, value in sorted(chain.from_iterable([dict1.items(),dict2.items(),dict3.items()]), key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    d.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)

print d
OrderedDict([('Frank', [200]), ('Steve', [30, 20]), ('Jamal', [26, 10]), ('Carl', [14])])
```

Or just sorted like following :

```
print sorted(chain.from_iterable([dict1.items(),dict2.items(),dict3.items()]), key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)


[('Frank', 200), ('Steve', 30), ('Jamal', 26), ('Steve', 20), ('Carl', 14), ('Jamal', 10)]
```